# Why does my xmlCode return nothing

Tags: c#, xml

I have xml code and I want to get action's value:

```
<msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'><k>randomKey</k></body></msg>
```

I've tried:

```
xmlCode.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["action"]
```

which outputs nothing.

Comment: Corrected the mistake

Comment: correct what mistake.. sounds like you need to delete the question if the issue has been corrected since you are really not providing any real details as to what the issue is `Which outputs nothing` means nothing to any of us

Comment: the problem is that it returns nothing when it should get action='rndK'

Comment: do a google search on how to parse xml look up how to use `XPATH` that's where I would start.. TGIF happy coding off to the weekend

Comment: If you haven't already fixed this, can you show us how `xmlCode` is initialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a little homework, I test your code and find your problem:

```
var a = XElement.Parse(@"<msg t='sys'><body action='rndK' r='-1'><k>randomKey</k></body></msg>");
var xmlNode = a.ToXmlDocument();
```

The above is just so I re-create your xmlNode. The `ToXmlDocument` can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/ChuckSavage/4991478).

Then we have the following...

```
var msg = xmlNode.ChildNodes[0];
```

`msg` is your first child node, if you'd separated it out like I did, then you'd see it in the debugger. The rest follows naturally...

```
var body = msg.ChildNodes[0];
var action = body.Attributes["action"];
string actionValue = action.Value;
```

The reason why your code: `xmlCode.ChildNodes[0].Attributes["action"]` returns nothing is the `msg` node doesn't contain an `action` attribute and therefore, you get nothing as a result.